# iPhone: Can't scroll over a UIWebView contained in a tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, ios6, scroll

I've seen many similar questions on the web, i've tried many approaches but none worked.

I have a UITableview which contains custom cells and some UIWebViews, the problems is that i can't scroll the UITableView if the scroll starts on the UIWebview.

The closest I got is by setting webView.userInteractionEnabled to NO but then I can't access the link anymore...

Do you have any idea or pointers on how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
webview.scrollView.setuserInteractionEnabled = NO
```

instead.